# A nullPointerException occurs when updaing a JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox, resultset

I want to update the jcombobox. So I removed all items first and then going to execute the query. I'm calling this method in a constructor and it's working fine. Also I'm calling this method in a button, and when that btn is pressed it gives me a nullpointerexception. combo box items were also removed.  So the problem is in line 5. How to fix this??

```
private void loadDataToCombo(String query,JComboBox combo) {  
      ResultSet result1= null;
    //removing existing items before adding
     combo.removeAllItems();
     result1 = DBOptions.executeSQLQuery(query); //line 5   

    try {
        while(result1.next()){
            String data = result1.getString(1);
            combo.addItem(data);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your JComboBox combo is null.

Comment: Use debuggger to find out which variable is null. It will be more efficient than asking us to find the error.

Comment: I'm passing it as a argument and then removing all items and then again adding items to it, Since im passing it, it can not be null.

Comment: I checked this statement using print method      DBOptions.executeSQLQuery(query), as I said this line was executed twice. First time it gives JDBC something. second time it doesn't show anything

Comment: `DBOptions.executeSQLQuery(query);` is probably returning null, so `result1.next()` throws an NPE.

Comment: what is the reason for that?? I'm using the same query that was used in the constructor. First it works.

Comment: Have you done the obvious test to see if DBOptions is null before you use it? Don't assume anything until you've proven it.

Comment: executeSQLQuery is a static method defined in the DBOptions class

Comment: Can you post the code for `executeSQLQuery`? And the stack trace for the NPE?

Answer (score 0):

If its on the click of the Button, please see that **have you initialized the Button..?**

```
JButton butt = new JButton();
```

Comment: I'm calling this method in the ActionPerformed method

Comment: Ya offcourse.... but have you  registered this ActionListener of whom actionPerformed() is a method of with the JButton....., if you have done it,,, please check that have you initialized the button before doing it.....

Comment: Im using netbeans, so when I executing this it should initialze. right??

Comment: No.... even if you use Eclipse, JDeveloper, etc , etc.... Its `you who need to Initialize it.....`

Comment: @Kumar: Based on the indicated line in the original post's code, I don't think that this is the problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `Also I'm calling this method in a button, and when that btn is pressed it gives me a nullpointerexception`, this line of OP pulled my attention

Comment: im pretty sure that line 4 is executed since all the items were removed.

Comment: @Kumar: it's the code *inside* of the JButton's ActionListener which is causing the NPE. Again there's a high likelihood that your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, the OP has not given his log cat....now there can be another reason that his connection to DB failed.... i can take only few guessed..till he gives the Logcat

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I think it is because you have actionlistner on the items. what I did is remove the actionlistener on the items.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my solution was to **replace** the combo event **actionperformed by the event mouseclicked**. This way, it does not catch the item or prevent you from adding them by `addItem()`.